# Не освобождается операционная память

Tags: c#, wpf, ram

При запуске программы стартовое окно занимает 17 мб оперативной памяти, из стартового окна создается новое, которое занимает 88 мб оперативной памяти, если закрыть это окно и вернуться к стартовому, то объем занятой памяти всё равно будет равен 88 мб. Как освободить оперативную память после закрытия окна?

Comment: что инициализируется вместе со вторым окном?

Comment: @Ni55aN, создается MediaElement, несколько вспомогательных переменных, осуществляется привязка громкости MediaElemnt-а к значению Slider.

Comment: Зачем это вам? Когда память будет реально нужна, её автоматически освободит сборщик мусора. Если он не срабатывает, значит реальной необходимости в памяти нет (или у вас memory leak).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, я то думал что она не освободится до тех пор, пока процесс не завершить. Так то это вообще не проблема, и вопрос отпал сам собой.

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov: Пожалуйста! К сборщику мусора надо привыкнуть, он неочевидный во многом.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В .NET память не освобождается в момент "закрытия окна". Объекты остаются висеть в куче до тех пор, пока их не зачистит сборщик мусора. Его можно заставить это сделать вызовами:

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

И даже после освобождения памяти в управляемой куче - рантайм может не сразу отдать освободившуюся память системе - а вдруг вы ее опять захотите выделить. Тем более что "выделенная память" - это не конкретные куски памяти на микросхеме, а просто зарезервированный в огромном виртуальном адресном пространстве кусочек.