# C#: почему не освобождается память?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день.

Я сейчас оптимизирую свой СМТП-windows service, ищу утечки памяти.  Я провел такой эксперимент (код ниже):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry( "[ " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +  "] Сервис запущен: " + ServiceName);
    _logHelper.WriteEvent("Сервис запущен: " + ServiceName);

    try
    {
        SmtpHelper smtpHelper = new SmtpHelper();
        ThreadStart(smtpHelper.Listen));
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(smtpHelper.Listen); // !!!

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry( ServiceName + " error: \n" + ex.ToString());
    }        
}
////////////////////////////////////////

public void Listen(object temp) //authDataObj
{
        //crash test+
        int[] array = new int[99999999];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = 99999999;
        }
        //crash test+
}
```

Грубо говоря, я входящий потом загружаю большим массивом, диспетчер задач показывает нагрузку "385 мб", но когда по идее поток должен завершиться, **память НЕ освобождается.**

> Как мне кажется, после того весь массив заполнится, поток завершится,
>   и память должна освободиться.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Почему память не освобождается?**
Спасибо

**UPD
Через 23 минуты сервис отпустил ресурсы, диспетчер показал 3,3Мб**

Comment: диспетчер задач - это очень толстый инструмент для измерения утечек. .NET память то освободил, но оставил у себя про запас. Вдругс снова выделять. А бегать к ОС за памяти - дольше, чем взять свою.

Comment: Для отслеживаня утечек пямяти лучше использовать VS Profiling Tools
или, например, решение от jetBrains https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/features/

Comment: спасибо. он подойдет для виндовс-сервиса?

Comment: Плюс уже сказанному, если сильно критично, можете дернуть GC.Collect() чтобы принудительно вызвать сборку мусора, но лучше этого не делать без реальной необходимости.

Comment: посмотрите еще этот вопрос и ответ. Ситуация как раз ваша и подробно объяснено что к чему. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461121/198316

Comment: @LeonardBertone, главное чтобы после оптимиации с использованием GC.Collect() не пришлось оптимизировать оптимизированное :) Лучше поискать другие способы оптимизации.

Comment: А еще похоже ваша тестовая структура попадает в  LOH (large object heap), который реже очищается.