# С#: нормальное ли это поведение потоков?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, консоль

Добрый день.

Вот мой код: (слушаю 25ый порт локальной машины):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 25);
            SMTP_Listener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            while (true)
            {
                Socket clientSocket = SMTP_Listener.AcceptSocket();

                if (clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    string _sessionId = clientSocket.GetHashCode().ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected: " + _sessionId);

                    new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        StartProcessing(clientSocket, _sessionId);
                        Console.WriteLine(">> Client thread is finished: " + _sessionId);
                    }).Start();
                }

            }
        }

        static void StartProcessing(Socket clientSocket, string _sessionId)
        {
            //Лимит сообщения
            int _maxMessageSize = 1000000000;
            //таймаут ажидания команды от клиента
            int _commandIdleTimeOut = 6000000;
            //время жизни сессии
            int _sessionIdleTimeOut = 80000;

            int[] arr = new int[1000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = i;
            }

             clientSocket.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(">> Socket closed for client " + _sessionId);
        }
    }
```

Вызываю код из другого приложения:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("machine_name", 25); 
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage("localm@bank.lan", "+380662367263@domen.lan");
            m.Body = i.ToString() + " (1)";
            client.Send(m);
            Console.WriteLine(">> " + i + " (1)");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">> " + i + " (2)");
        }
    }
```

**Вопрос в производительности** - при запуске приложение оно занимает **7,156 Мб** оперативы, но после 30 подключений, программа начинает занимать уже **7,548 Мб** , но через  17 минут нагрузка упала до **7,308 Мб** и такой уже и остается на протяжении.

> Как я понимаю, если рхитектура приложения верная, то нагрузка должна
>   вернуться к первоначальному уровню, т.е. **7,156 Мб** оперативы, но
>   этого не происходит.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина того, что память программной не освобождается?**

Comment: чем мерили "оперативу"?

Comment: В диспетчере задач!

Comment: вы же уже задавали такой вопрос, и его как дубликат отметили: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503796/c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Не факт, что память не освобождается. Проверьте лучше с memory profiler'ом. (Например, Ants.)