# Не освобождается память приложения С#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пишу приложение windows form для "общения" ПК и Arduino посредством COM интерфейса. Arduino отправляет строку формата, например "100;2#". Отправленные данные из Arduino ловлю с помощью:

```
        SerPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        void DataReceivedHandler(object sender_handler, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs ex)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender_handler;
            string data = sp.ReadExisting();
            test(data)
        }
```

Однако заметил, что после каждого обработанного сообщения от Arduino приложение растёт по памяти и никак его не высвобождает. void DataReceivedHandlerpublic находится в Form1().

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MMDeviceEnumerator DevEmul = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        MMDeviceCollection allAudioDevice = DevEmul.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(EDataFlow.eRender, EDeviceState.DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE);
        MMDeviceCollection allRecordDevice = DevEmul.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(EDataFlow.eCapture, EDeviceState.DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE);

        //Выводим все активные устройства воспроизведения
        for (int i = 0; i < allAudioDevice.Count; i++)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(allAudioDevice[i].FriendlyName);
        }

        //Указываем параметр Checked устройству, которое сейчас по-умолчанию
        MMDevice defaultAudioDevice = GetDefaultDevice();
        checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.FindString(defaultAudioDevice.FriendlyName), CheckState.Checked);

        //Отслеживаем изменение в COM
        SerPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        void DataReceivedHandler(object sender_handler, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs ex)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender_handler;
            string data = sp.ReadExisting();
            test(data);
        }

        void test(string indata)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                if (indata == "GetVolume")
                {
                    MMDeviceCollection GetVolumeDevice = DevEmul.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(EDataFlow.eRender, EDeviceState.DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE);

                    string SendStr = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                        {
                            SendStr += checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString() + ";" + i + "^" + GetVolumeDevice[i].AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar * 100 + "#";
                            if (defaultAudioDevice.FriendlyName == GetVolumeDevice[i].FriendlyName) SendStr += "1$";
                            else SendStr += "0$";
                        }
                    }
                    SerPort.Write(SendStr);
                    //MessageBox.Show(SendStr);
                }
                else
                {
                    String bufferStr = "";
                    int readVolume = 0;
                    int readID = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < indata.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (indata[i] != ';' && indata[i] != '#')
                        {
                            bufferStr += indata[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (indata[i] == ';') readVolume = Int32.Parse(bufferStr);
                            if (indata[i] == '#')
                            {
                                readID = Int32.Parse(bufferStr);
                                textBox1.Text = readVolume.ToString();
                                progressBar1.Value = readVolume;
                                allAudioDevice[readID].AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = (float)readVolume / 100;
                            }
                            bufferStr = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Пробовал не вызывать функцию test(data), а заменить её на MessageBox.Show(data), но это никак не повлияло на ситуацию. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Посмотрите, есть ли у типов MMDevice* метод Dispose, если есть, то надо использовать для очистки объектов, или описывать их через детективу using. И сериал порт вероятно тоже надо закрывать после работы с ним, как минимум, а так-же отписывать от евентов, `SerPort.DataReceived -=`

Comment: @NewView Как я уже говорил, я пробовал вообще не использовать функцию test(), дабы предотвратить создание объектов MMDevice*, а просто выводить полученную строку от Arduino с помощью MessageBox - не помогло. Где именно стоит отписаться от евента с помощью SerPort.DataReceived -= ?

Comment: На сколько сильно растет по памяти? Просто, сборка мусора недетерминированный процесс, который срабатывает в наиболее подходящее место или когда оперативка подходит к концу

Comment: @iluxa1810 с момента запуска программа занимает 6мб. Без проблем смог довести до 12мб отправкой порядка 200 команд с Arduino. Не то чтобы это проблематично и ресурсов не хватит, жизнь программы врятли сможет съесть всё, но хотелось бы понять причину.
Принцип всей этой конструкции такой, что с помощью аппаратной основы и Arduino я собираюсь управлять громкостью аудио устройств на ПК. При повороте ручки энкодера Arduino передаёт какое значение громкости и какому устройству установить, а программа читает эти параметры и собственно устанавливает необходимое значение.

Comment: Ну, сборщик мусора может не срабатывать так как у вас есть еще свободная оперативка. А что будет если вызвать GC.Collect() после ваших 200 команд?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461121/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @iluxa1810 GC.Collect() вызывать по завершению функции test() или лучше завязать на таймер?

Comment: Попробуйте по завершению и почитайте ссылку выше. Сборщик мусора не обязан сразу возвращать память. Вообще, его поведение не определено и он может спать пока оперативки достаточно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, я обращал внимание на эту статью, но там рассматривается создание новых окон, когда в моём случае всё размещено на одной форме. Вечером попробую поэксперементировать с GC.Collect(), по результату отпишусь, спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте профилер в студии, он иногда помогает найти место где и на что выделяется память, потом можно делать выводы что с этим делать.

Answer (score 0):

SerialPort использует потоки threadpool для вызова обработчика событий DataReceived это может приводить к большому пулу потоков если функция обработки не успевает за портом. Диагностика этого возможна из меню Debug -> Windows -> Threads. Так-же обратите внимание на количество событий ErrorReceived.

Для борьбы с этим используйте свойство Handshake для настройки управления потоком, или можно отказаться от использования эвента DataReceived и получать все в ручную:

```
while (SerPort.IsOpen)
{
    uint c = SerPort.ReadByte();
```

Comment: спасибо за советы (в частности использования профилирования)
Судя по всему всё выделение памяти связанно с объектами используемой библиотеки CoreAudioApi, я верно понимаю?
Скриншот отчета: https://ibb.co/jFUHQ0

Comment: Похоже на то, но.. посмотрите списки тредов, это может быть и они с запущенным куском КореАудио, но не завершенные. И так-же, если у объекта есть Dispose, его надо чистить явно.

Comment: К сожалению у объектов MMDevice нет Dispose, да и в функции test() объект типа MMDeviceCollection создаётся только один раз при запуске Arduino, когда она отправляет "GetVolume".
С моим опытом программирования дебаг потоков не много чём сказал, буду пытаться разобраться разбираться.  Спасибо за советы